# How to change value using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, styles

I have got this code

```
        var PaddingBottom = $('input#padding-bottom');
        PaddingBottom.on('change', function () {
            var img = $('img');
            var newPaddingBottom = this.value;

        $('head').append( '<style>' + img + '{ padding-bottom:' + newPaddingBottom + 'px;} </style>');
        });
```

but when value of the `input#container-padding-bottom` is changed it everytime add `<style>` to `<head>`

**My question is:** how to change `newPaddingBottom` value without adding `<style>` to `<head>` several times ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add css to the page to change style attributes.  You can change them directly...

```
var PaddingBottom = $('input#padding-bottom');

PaddingBottom.on('change', function () {
    $('img').css("padding-bottom", this.value + "px");
});
```

See here for more information...

http://api.jquery.com/css/